# Выражение "с приветом"

Tags: фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему о человеке со странностями говорят "с приветом"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос часто обсуждается на разного рода форумах, но исчерпывающего объяснения я не знаю.
Совершенно очевидно, что первоисточником послужила принятая некогда форма дружеского письма: подпись "С приветом, Имяреков" или обращение "С приветом из Нью-Васюков!"

Однако мотивация переноса на человека со странностями не ясна. Возможно причиной послужило как раз упомянутое обращение, обыгранное как "С приветом из сумасшедшего дома".